# Наследование с вложенными классами

Tags: java, наследование

```
class SinglyLinkedList extends AbstractList {
protected Node first;
protected Node last;
protected int size;

static class Node {
    Node next;
    Object val;

    Node(Node next, Object val) {
        this.next = next;
        this.val = val;
    }

    Node() {
        this.next = null;
        this.val = null;
    }
}
```

Я собираюсь от односвязного списка унаследовать двусвязный список, при этом в вложенном классе, который будет находиться в DoublyLinkedList должно быть ещё одно поле и соответственно конструктор.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList extends SinglyLinkedList {
static class Node extends SinglyLinkedList.Node {
    Node prev;

    Node(Node next, Object val, Node prev) {
        super(next, val);
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

Уверен, что делаю это не правильно.

Comment: Последние предложение подразумевает, что вы предложите правильный вариант или укажите на ошибку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно будет вынести общую логику списков в абстрактный класс и унаследовать от него оба списка. Если `Node` хранит только состояние, то пусть он будет отличаться в реализациях списка. Либо его можно вынести в `protected` / [package-private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) классы, для того чтобы была видимость только внутри пакета.

Статические внутренние классы не нарушают [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), с их помощью обычно выполняют логическую группировку сущностей внутри класса. В вашем случае плохо то, что вы усложняете дизайн, что сопряжено в последующей тестируемостью и расширяемостью кода, не извлекая при этом никакой практической пользы.

Примеры из JDK:

- [AbstractSequentialList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.java)
- [LinkedList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java)